Checking for damage of radio
I wanted to ask, how likely is it that a Icom A16E is damaged if you accidentally hit the transmit button without an antenna for less than a second. Is there a way to test if damage has occurred?

This completely depends on the TR Switch & the Duplexer used in the RF front end. While most of those modules can tolerate high reflections, there is a chance that yours cannot. That being said, not sustaining the open load condition certainly helps limit the potential damage. Ultimately, you must check the manufacturer's reported numbers on how much isolation the RF frontend can handle. To test for damages, just plug the antenna back in and see if it works as intended! :)

@a360pilot Thank you! This is very helpful :)

The manual says in many places not to transmit without the antenna.
This is not a good answer, however, these sorts of commercial transceivers are fairly tolerant of operating without the antenna.
The quick check is to see if it works. Perhaps use it for ground communications next time you taxi.
A more complex check requires an RF power meter suitable for VHF bands and a 50 ohm dummy load good for > 3 W. See if you get about 1.8 W with no modulation (i.e., don't talk whilst taking the measurement) when transmitting.

Thank you, this is very helpful. A local radio association might have a RW power meter which I will try to test with. However, the easiest is, as you said, is to test transmitting while taxiing etc.
